# Problems with curses C++

Tags: c++, windows, curses, pdcurses

I've recently started to use PDcurses for Windows.
I wrote a simple program that creates a window and moves a character according to the user's inputs, going up for 'w', down for 's' and so on.

There are 2 weird things that happen:

1. Whenever I move the character down holding "s" it disappears not allowing the user to see the movement.
2. Whenever I move the character sideways it leaves a "trail" (sort of) blue if it goes to the right and red if it goes to the left.

I Attach a short GIF in which you can see the first problem and a screenshot for the second (since the quality of the recording was not enough to see the trail).
[image: Animation showing the character disappearing]
[image: Static image showing character]

Here's the C++ code. It draws at the at the beginning of the loop, scans for inputs in the middle, and refreshes the screen at the end. I set the `getch()` not to interrupt the execution with `nodelay()`.

```
initialize();
WINDOW* stage= createstage();
int ywindow,xwindow,heightwindow,widthwindow;

getbegyx(stage,ywindow,xwindow);
getmaxyx(stage,heightwindow,widthwindow);
heightwindow--;
widthwindow--;
int x = xwindow+1, y = ywindow+1;
char c = '@';


while(TRUE){

    box(stage,0,0);
    wmove(stage,y,x);
    wprintw(stage,"%c",'@');

    c=getch();
    if(c=='w' && y-1>ywindow){
        y--;
    }
    if (c=='s' && y+1<heightwindow){
        y++;
    }
    if(c=='d' && x+1<widthwindow){
        x++;
    }
    if(c=='a' && x-1>xwindow){
        x--;
    }
    wrefresh(stage);
    Sleep(16);
    wclear(stage);
}
```

Comment: This could be an artifact of timing and screen refreshes. What happens if you change the delay in the `Sleep` call? Or draw the character before drawing the box? Or change the order so that you get the character, redraw the screen, refresh, then sleep?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Thanks for the reply. Setting the Sleep time to be >60 solves the first problem but of course the character would have more delay when moved and the trails also remain. Trying all the other suggestions does not fix anything instead.

Comment: 1. This is not a complete example program. 2. I strongly suggest using `napms()` (built into curses, allows background processing) instead of `Sleep()` (Windows-specific, halts the thread). 3. Consider erasing and redrawing just the character instead of the whole window. 4. However, the "trails" sound like an artifact of the terminal, not something you're going to be able to fix at the curses level.

Answer (score 0):

Update:
First of all I attach the complete source of the program:

```
#include "curses.h"
#include <windows.h>

void disableselection(){
  HANDLE hInput;
  DWORD prev_mode;
  hInput = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
  GetConsoleMode(hInput, &prev_mode);
  SetConsoleMode(hInput, prev_mode & ENABLE_EXTENDED_FLAGS);
}

void disableresizing(){
  HWND consoleWindow = GetConsoleWindow();
  SetWindowLong(consoleWindow, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(consoleWindow, GWL_STYLE) & ~WS_MAXIMIZEBOX & ~WS_SIZEBOX);
}

void initialize(){
  initscr();
  curs_set(0);
  disableselection();
  disableresizing();
  noecho();     
  nodelay(stdscr,TRUE);    
}

WINDOW* createstage(int starty=0, int startx=0, int height=LINES, int width=COLS-COLS*1/5){
  WINDOW* win=newwin(height-starty,width-startx,starty,startx);
  refresh();
  return win;
}

void end(WINDOW* stage){
  clear();
  refresh();
  nodelay(stdscr,FALSE);
  printw("press something to exit");
  getch();
  endwin();
}

int main(){
  initialize();
  WINDOW* stage= createstage();
  int ywindow,xwindow,heightwindow,widthwindow;
  getbegyx(stage,ywindow,xwindow);
  getmaxyx(stage,heightwindow,widthwindow);
  heightwindow--;
  widthwindow--;
  int x = xwindow+1, y = ywindow+1;
  char c = '@';
  while(TRUE){
    box(stage,0,0);
    wmove(stage,y,x);
    waddch(stage,'@');
    wrefresh(stage);
    c=wgetch(stage);
    if(c=='w' && y-1>ywindow){
      y--;
    }
    if (c=='s' && y+1<heightwindow){
      y++;
    }
    if(c=='d' && x+1<widthwindow){
      x++;
    }
    if(c=='a' && x-1>xwindow){
      x--;
    }
    napms(16);
    werase(stage);
    wrefresh(stage);
 }
 end(stage);
}
```

As you can see I modified the loop.
The result is that now there are no "trails" and when the character moves down it doesn't disappear.
Another issue has come up though.

The box (precisely the top side) flickers whenever I move. This happens even If I put the `box(stage,0,0);` call at the start of the loop.

I've tried drawing the box using `stdscr` and also creating a subwindow to use as main stage and drawing the box in the parent window.
Another thing I tried is removing the Windows API functions thinking they were conflicting.
None of these ideas worked.